# What is the font used in IE 10 source?

Tags: font-identification

I would like to change my font in Aptana to this font, but i don't know what font family internet explorer source is using. Regards.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) to me:

[image: Consolas screenshot]

It's definitely a monospace font. Consolas was one of the ClearType fonts designed for Vista and later, and, as the Wiki article says, "[Consolas] is the only standard Windows Vista font with a slash through the zero character."

You can set Consolas as a font for your site and trust that a large portion of Windows users will have it (everyone who has Vista, 7, or 8, plus lots of XP people who have later versions of Office installed as well as Mac users who have Office on their machines), but if you want to embed it as a web font, you can look for a license on a commercial site such as [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/consolas).

Comment: @tudor Happy to help! If you like the monospace look but want to experiment with other fonts that look a bit different and are free to embed on your site as a web font, check out Google Fonts and use the Filter on the right to select Monospaced fonts. Source Code Pro is a pretty robust choice - it has seven weights!

Answer (score 0):

I believe they use "Tahoma".

But this is dependent on what you have set as your system default font.

Comment: I use Windows 8 and haven't changed any default font settings. I believe that is the font, thank you :)

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)